# jQuery each loop only apply class to specific element that has substring

Tags: jquery

Having some issues of looping over elements and adding class based on their href.
The class seems to be applying to all elements even if those elements aren't having the substring in their href.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#special-link">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/normallink1">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/normallink2">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
  if(_this.attr('href').substr('special')!==0){
    _this.addClass('special_link');
  }
});
```

I have also set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9oxoog4w/1/).
Any apologies if this might be a duplicate, I did have a look around though before posting the question.

Thanks.

Comment: `.substr('special')!==0` should be `.indexOf('special') > -1`

Comment: Why not just: `$('a[href*=special]').addClass('special_link');`?  https://jsfiddle.net/9oxoog4w/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff, if you poor it into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @asturnick ALOK posted it as answer, feel free to accept it instead :)

Comment: @A.Wolff, thanks a lot anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No need for each loop

   ```
   $("a[href*='special']").addClass('special_link');
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you,

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    if(_this.attr('href').indexOf('special') > -1){
        _this.addClass('special_link');
    }
});
```

Comment: Works great as well!